How can I use the iPhone's keyboard within iPhone Mirroring on my computer?
I sometimes want to run the iPhone Duolingo app via iPhone Mirroring on my MacBook Pro (MBP).  However, I can find no way to make the iOS keyboard that would normally appear if I were running the app directly on my phone appear within iPhone Mirroring.  Is it possible to make the native iOS onscreen keyboard appear in this scenario?
The only workaround I can find for entering forwign text is to open up a separate text editor on my MBP, use one of the MBP's keyboards to produce the desired text, and then copy-paste into the iPhone Mirroring app.  Aside from the extra steps required, the iOS keyboard for a foreign language is often much cleaner to use than any of the keyboards available in macOS.

Isn't using the Mac keyboard to enter text in the Mirroring window way easier than using the mouse to "type" on the small onscreen keyboard (if it would show)?

Not for foreign languages. Mandarin input, Czech input, Russian input, Ukrainian input and (surely) input for many other languages is much easier with the iPhone keyboard, where it will automatically display the alternative phonetic system, alphabet, and/or diacritics directly on the key caps.

Wouldn't the Mac onscreen keyboard be more suitable in these situations, or at least be useable as well?

For several language, the Mac onscreen keyboard is still less usable than the iOS keyboard that I use for that language.  In addition, as I mentioned in my post, there are separate steps to get the output into a text editor, followed by copy-pasting into the iOS app.
